# How can I implement SEO-friendly URL with php?

Tags: php, apache, seo

I'm currently using Apache HTTP + PHP + MongoDB.

I'm trying to implement "stackoverflow"-like url which is SEO friendly.

Should I read a title from each article and somehow send that to Apache? If so, how can I do that?

So that Apache can handle that the title string with mod_rewrite and having URL like

```
www.example.com/123/seo-friendly-page
```

Give me some ideas with an example snippet code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create SEO friendly URL's by the help of .htaccess. there is a lot of tutorial on the web about that.... here is a [LINK.](http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/create-seo-friendly-urls-using-mod-rewrite-and-php-part-1.html)

and if you want more secure with php and mysql..... then.....[LINK](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/04/seo-friendly-urls-with-php.html)

I think this is helpful for you....