# how to change the url query string to slash using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using the query string to detail page but I want to redirect SEO friendly URL like with the slash. I've used the below code to access the page url like `http://localhost/mysite/product/pid/cat/subcat`. It's working fine but I've to redirect 'product/pid/cat/subcat' when I click this link 'detail.php?pid=123&cat=mens&subcat=shirt'

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ detail.php?pid=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Point of note, it's not at all certain that, these days, Google cares much about your URL structure when it comes to query string vs slashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement SEO-friendly URL with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035666/how-can-i-implement-seo-friendly-url-with-php)

Comment: It's not duplicate. I've implemented SEO friendly URL using above code. I'm asking I just want to redirect to this URL 'product/pid/cat/subcat' using mod_rewrite since I'm using this url ( 'detail.php?pid=123&cat=mens&subcat=shirt' ) in more places. so I just redirect to slash url when I click query string link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use those two rules in your root htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/mysite/detail\.php\?pid=([^&\s]+)&cat=([^&\s]+)&subcat=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ product/%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ detail.php?pid=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I tried this. but still it goes to 'detail.php?pid=123&cat=mens&subcat=shirt' when I click the link '<a href=''detail.php?pid=123&cat=mens&subcat=shirt''>'product</a>

Comment: What's your full url after clicking on it ?

Comment: mysite.com/detail.php?pid=123&cat=mens&subcat=shirt'. this is my full URL after clicking on it. But it should redirect to mysite.com/detail/123/mens/shirt'

Comment: I tested it to make sure and it works. The only thing I can see right now is you should add a leading slash in your `href` (eg `href="/detail.php?xxx"`). From what page (and full url you see in your browser's bar) do you click the "old" link ?

Comment: changed it like this "<a href='http://localhost/mysite/detail.php?pid=12&cat=mens&subcat=shirt'>item</a>". when I click item the browser url is http://localhost/mysite/detail.php?pid=12&cat=mens&subcat=shirt. not http://localhost/mysite/product/12/mens/shirt

Comment: Ok so you didn't tell me your site was in a subfolder called `mysite`. Just move your htaccess in that subfolder and check my updated answer.